# Running a Thread Repeteadly With Time Intervals

Tags: android, multithreading

In my Android App. i try to use a thread for doing some stuff repeteadly with given time interval. I thought a solution basically, as you see below.

```
public void run(){

     while(true){

       sleep(5000); 

       doSomeStuff();

      }
}
```

But i guess, this code has some logical problems doing what i want. What should i do for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)